# Fiware: configure orion context broker port

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

I'm using [Orion Context Broker](http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker) but the default port is not valid in my organization (a firewall is filtering out 1026 for external connections).

How can I change the Orion Context Broker default port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Orion Context Broker service port using the `-port` command line option. For example, if you want to use port 9999, run contextBroker using the following:

```
contextBroker ... -port 9999
```

Check the [Orion Context Broker administration manual](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/index.html) for details.