# No JSON object could be decoded- orion context broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying out orion context broker comunication on two CentOS 6.6 machines. On the target machine I did:

```
./accumulator-server.py 1028 /accumulate mywebpage.lan on
```

And on my local machine I did:

```
[DevF12@localhost ~]$ (curl mywebpage.lan:1028/v1/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool ) <<EOF
> {
>     "contextElements": [
>         {
>             "type": "Room",
>             "isPattern": "false",
>             "id": "Room2",
>             "attributes": [
>             {
>                 "name": "temperature",
>                 "type": "float",
>                 "value": "777"
>             },
>             {
>                 "name": "pressure",
>                 "type": "integer",
>                 "value": "711"
>             }
>             ]
>         }
>     ],
>     "updateAction": "APPEND"
> }
> EOF
```

The result on the target machine is:

```
POST http://mywebpage.lan:1028/v1/updateContext
Content-Length: 456
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Host: mywebpage.lan:1028
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{    "contextElements": [        {            "type": "Room",            "isPattern": "false",            "id": "Room2",            "attributes": [            {                "name": "temperature",                "type": "float",                "value": "777"            },            {                "name": "pressure",                "type": "integer",                "value": "711"            }            ]        }    ],    "updateAction": "APPEND"}=======================================

192.168.1.11 - - [14/Apr/2015 15:07:36] "POST /v1/updateContext HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And the message I get from the local machine is:

```
No JSON object could be decoded
```

So, what does this all mean?

**1. Is the 200 code saying that it is successfully creating Room2?**

**2. Why am I getting the could not decode JSON then?**

**3. All of this brings up another question, does this mean that the weather station [described in my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531646/how-do-i-configure-context-broker-accept-post-requests-from-my-remote-sensor/29533030?noredirect=1#comment47232739_29533030) also has to run on CentOS in order to send context broker messages?**

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a "conceptual" misunderstanding in your test. You are sending the updateContext to 1028 which is *not* the port of CB (the one supposed to process updateContext messages) but the accumulator port (which purpose is process notifyContext message sent by CB as a consequence of updateContext messages, but *not* processing updateContext messages themselves).

Typically, Orion Context Broker runs in port 1026 by default.

Taking into account this, the specific answers are:

- *Is the 200 code saying that it is successfully creating Room2?* No. 200 reported by accumulator just mean that the accumulator has received and acknowledge a message (any message, given that accumulator is a "dummy" application just for testing, it is not doing any real processing of that).
- *Why am I getting the could not decode JSON then?* Try to remove `| python -mjson.tool` in the curl command line.
- *All of this brings up another question, does this mean that the weather station described in my previous post also has to run on CentOS in order to send context broker messages?* Not sure about the "weather station" in your case, but if you mean the client sending updateContext to CB, it doesn't need to run in CentOS. The only requirements for the client is to be compliant with Orion API and have network connectivity to that host (and port) where Orion is listening.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should target port 1026 and not port 1028?
Because I am having trouble in CentOS to open port 1026 in firewall- I get something called cap instead of 1026.
Is there a way to change the default context broker port?

Comment: you can change the port Orion is using with the command-line option ```--port NN```. Also, don't worry aobut the name "cap". This is just a naming convention that the OS is using from some conf file. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: Please check the following Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292416/fiware-configure-orion-context-broker-port